# Compare element and index of list

Tags: python

I want to be able to compare two lists of strings. If both list share the same element in the same index then add 1, else add 0.

my code:

```
TARGET = "Hello World"

# converts target to list
list_target = list(TARGET)

...
    def eval_fit(self, dna):
        score = 0
        for i in dna:
            if dna.index(i) == list_target.index(i):
                score + 1
            else:
                score + 0
        return score

class Population:
    def __init__(self):

        pop_num = 5
        population = []
        create = [Individual(birth(), 0)
                for i in range(pop_num)]


        for obj in create:
            population.append(obj)

        for obj in population:
            print(obj.dna)

        for obj in population:
            print(obj.convert(obj.dna), " score: ", obj.eval_fit(obj.dna))
```

outcome:

```
['v', 't', 'D', 'P', 'Y', 'l', 'x', '7', 'p', '9', 'Q']
[' ', '7', 'g', 'h', '7', 'w', 'T', '4', '7', 'h', 'D']
['m', 'n', 'P', 'j', 'Y', 'i', 'P', 'g', 'm', 's', 'U']
['G', 'n', 'm', 'W', '7', 'r', 'k', 'n', 'F', 'V', ' ']
['n', 'r', 'i', 'i', 'k', 't', 'v', 'x', 'Z', 'Z', 'i']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tonya\Desktop\realProjects\genetic_algorithm\sketch.py", line 67, in <module>
    Population()
  File "C:\Users\tonya\Desktop\realProjects\genetic_algorithm\sketch.py", line 62, in __init__
    print(obj.convert(obj.dna), " score: ", obj.eval_fit(obj.dna))
  File "C:\Users\tonya\Desktop\realProjects\genetic_algorithm\sketch.py", line 40, in eval_fit
    if dna.index(i) == list_target.index(i):
ValueError: 'v' is not in list
[Finished in 0.685s]
```

I'm not sure if turning strings into lists is the best way to compare them and reward points based on correct position of characters.

Comment: The problem is this line: `if dna.index(i) == list_target.index(i)`, this is wrong. `.index` gives you the *first index*, not to mention, this is a quadratic time algorithm, and as you noticed, is raising a ValueError when the letter isn't found, which you are failing to handle. But don't do this. Instead, you can keep both as strings, you don't need lists, just do: `sum(x = y for x,y in zip(dna, target))` which is constant space and linear time.

Comment: `score + 1` should be `score += 1`. And `score + 0` should just be omitted entirely, you don't have to do anything to add 0 to the variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you meant `sum(x == y ...)`

Comment: @azundo I did. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga this worked